# Django new ForeignKey field based on existing field

Tags: python, django, model, foreign-keys, default

I am trying to do the following but can't find a good solution on the documentation or on stackoverflow.

I have an existing database with ~1000 users with this model:

```
class Student(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

But I finally decided to use a separate model to handle schools :

```
class Student(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True)
    school = models.ForeignKey('School')

class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
```

How can I handle all the existing students, knowing that for the future students, I will be asking the school foreignkey directly in the suscription form ?

Answer (score 4):

Simplest solution wolud be to create auto migration, that will be something like this (listing only operations):

```
    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='School',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('name', models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='Student',
            name='school',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, to='testapp.School', null=True),
        ),
    ]
```

I've edited model Student, so now ForeignKey can be null, you can remove null value in AlterField on the end of migration if you're sure that every `Student` will have `School` assigned.

Now you should edit this migration by splitting AlterField into 3 separate operations (in sequence): [`RenameField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#renamefield) (to rename existing school char field to for example school_name), [`AddField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#addfield) (to add ForeignKey to school model) and [`RemoveField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#removefield) (to remove old, unneeded char field).

Now, insert [`RunPython`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#runpython) operation between `AddField` and `RemoveField` and inside that operation run code that will create new School objects (if there is no such object in database) and assign object to your `Student`.

In simple words: migration will create new model, named `School`, rename old field `school` to `school_name`, create new field `school` (`ForeignKey` to `School`) in model `Student`, iterate through all studens creating new `School` objects and assigning it into students and on last step, remove old `school_name` field (previously named `school`).

You can also provide reverse code into `RunPython` so you can reverse that migration without data loss.

Answer (score 2):

If you would want to do it live, using the ORM, you could rename the `Student.school` field to `Student.school_old`, then add the `Student.school` ForeignKey, and use the following snippet to make sure the data is ok:

```
for student in Student.objects.filter(school__isnull=False):
    try:
        school = School.objects.get(name=student.school_old)
    except School.DoesNotExist:
        school = School.objects.create(name=student.school_old)
    student.school = school
    student.save()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the "right" way to go, since we have migrations now. This would be a simple and quick solution to do though.

Comment: There's a `get_or_create` function in Django. Your try-except is obsolete. Plus objects.create() saves the object.